# Google App Engine on NetBeans 7

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-7, netbeans7.0

Is there any pluggin or alternative way to use Google App Engine on Netbeans **7**?

- deploy
- code completion
- ...

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it to work with netbeans 7.0 by using the kenai plugin for Netbeans 6.9: http://kenai.com/downloads/nbappengine/NetBeans69/updates.xml.

Here you have the [installation instructions](http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/pages/NBInstall). Of course: replace the links proposed with the link I provided (which is not listed on the page itself... Actually I found it by removing `/Latest_NetBeans68/updates.xml` from the other path).

I think it stopped working with 7.0.1 though.

Answer (score 3):

A new plugin version for NetBeans 7.2 is available.

The settings file is located at

https://kenai.com/downloads/nbappengine/NetBeans7.2/updates.xml

Installation instructions (for older versions) are [here](https://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/pages/NBInstall).

Comment: Thanks for updating but I think it's a bit late as everybody is talking about netbeans 7.3 now

Comment: The plugin for Nb7.2 has a bug. I've fixed it. When test I'l try to upload it to Github.